# Is it fastest to access a byte than a bit? Why?

Tags: performance, byte, bit

The question is very straight: is it fastest to access a byte than a bit? If I store 8 booleans in a byte will it be slower when I have to compare them than if I used 8 bytes? Why?

Comment: This is micro-optimization gone mad. If you're working on a project where you really need to worry about things like the performance of bytes vs. bits (which might be legit in very real, but a very small fraction of specialized software), you should probably be coding an Assembler, with absolutely nothing between you and the processor.

Comment: FYI, it is probably faster to access a processor word than it is to access a byte or bit.  E.g. (for many processors) a 32 bit numeric value.  The fastest chunk to access at once depends on if you're talking about in-cache, in-memory, off the disk, off the wire, etc.  There are a lot more factors than this, too.  The question as asked is very broad, nearly as broad as computer science...

Comment: @MerlynMorgan-Graham Indeed. I'd like to second the point that your question cannot be definitively answered as operations are optimized differently depending on hardware, purpose, and utility.

Comment: @normalocity No it's not. First, it's education. That's never a bad thing. Second, if they want to optimize any kind of algorithm that deals with information at this level, it's an important question. Regardless of language (of which they didn't specify by the way).

Comment: Whatever it is you're doing, *stop it*. Unless you're working on a project where nanosecond differences matter (which is unlikely) this isn't a question you need to be asking.  Premature optimization is *bad*.

Comment: @BrianRoach Seriously? They didn't ask your opinion about the state of a project in a language that they didn't specify with a purpose unknown targeted for a machine that's unspecified. Stop making assumptions. It's a valid question. Just really much too abstract.

Comment: If you couldn't gather from the flurry of activity and die off... you need to be more specific. What do you want to optimize? With what purpose? In what language? What's your target machine?

Comment: If you have a reasonable lot of data (enough so that performance is a problem), caching is probably going to be a bigger problem then the single cycle it usually takes to extract a bit from a byte. So bits are probably going to be better. Then again maybe not, what architecture are you coding for?

Answer (score 4):

Chances are no. The smallest addressable unit of memory in most machines today is a byte. In most cases, you can't address or access by bit.

In fact, accessing a specific bit might be even more expensive because you have to build a mask and use some logic.

EDIT:

Your question mentions "compare", I'm not sure exactly what you mean by that. But in some cases, you perform logic very efficiently on multiple booleans using bitwise operators if your booleans are densely packed into larger integer types.

**As for which to use:** array of bytes (with one boolean per byte), or a densely packed structure with one boolean per bit is a **space-effiicency trade-off**. For some applications that need to store a massive amount of bools, dense packing is better since it saves memory.

Answer (score 2):

The underlying hardware that your code runs on is built to access bytes (or longer words) from memory.  To read a bit, you have to read the entire byte, and then mask off the bits you don't care about, and possibly also shift to get the bit into the ones position.  So the instructions to access a bit are a superset of the instructions to access a byte.

Comment: I would also add that it's safe to assume that byte access is faster than bit access simply because assuming the reverse can be detrimental if you're optimizing for speed. In general, worst case is that they're the same speed. Best case is that byte access operations are optimized on specific processors.

Answer (score 1):

It may be faster to store the data as bits for a different reason - if you need to traverse and access many 8-bit sets of flags in a row. You will perform more ops per boolean flag, but you will traverse less memory by having it packed in fewer bytes. You will also be able to test multiple flags in a single operation, although you may be able to do this with bools to some extent as well, as long as they lie within a single machine word.

The memory latency penalty is far higher than register bit twiddling. In the end, only profiling the code on the hardware on which it will actually run will tell you which way is best.

Answer (score 1):

From a hardware point of view, I would say that in general all the bit masking and other operations in the best case might occur within a single clock (resulting in no different), but that entirely depends on hardware layer that you likely won't ever know the specifics of, and as such you cannot bank on it.

It's worth pointing out that things like the .NET `system.collections.bitarray` uses a 32bit integer array underneath to store it's bit data. There is likely a performance reason behind this implementation (even if only in a general case that 32bit words perform above average), I would suggest reading up about the inner workings of that might be revealing.

From a coding point of view, it really depends what you're going to do with the bits afterwards. That is to say if you're going to store your data in booleans such as:

```
bool a0, a1, a2, a3, a4, a5, a6, a7;
```

And then in your code you compare them one by one (and most of them together):

```
if ( a0 && a1 && !a2 && a3 && !a4 && (!a5 || a6) || a7) {
...
}
```

Then you will find that it will be faster (and likely neater in code) to use a bit mask. But really the only time this would matter is if you're going to be running this code millions of times in a high performance or time critical environment.

I guess what I'm getting at here is that you should do whatever your coding standards say (and if you don't have any or they don't consider such details then just do what looks neatest for your application and need).

But I highly suggest trying to look around and read a blog or two explaining the inner workings of the .NET `system.collections.bitarray`.

Answer (score 1):

This depends on the kind of processor and motherboard data bus, i.e. 32 bit data bus will compare your data faster if you collect them into "word"s rather than "bool"s or "byte"s.... 
This is only valid when you are writing in assembly language when you can compare each instruction how many cycles it takes .... but since you are using compiler then it is almost the same.
However, collecting booleans into words or integers will be useful in saving memory required for variables.

Answer (score 0):

Computers tend to access things in words. Accessing a bit is slower because it requires more effort:

Imagine I said something to you, then said "oh change my second word to instead".
Now imagine my edit instead was "oh, change the third letter in the second word to 's'".

Which requires more thinking on your part?

Comment: -1 Computers may or may not access things in words (of 8 bits). Most certainly modern computers do not most of the time these days (depending on how that access occurs). I'd like to travel back to 1985 too, but that isn't happening.